# What noise.types are implemented within blender?

Tags: python

I am trying to get the hang of noise / perlin noise / simplex noise for procedural generation of models and textures.

I am using `mathutils.noise.noise()` for getting a noise value. The api is mentioning different noise.types within this module. http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/mathutils.noise.html
For example: `mathutils.noise.noise(position, noise_basis=noise.types.STDPERLIN)`

Unfortunately there aren't any stated.
Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Blender python console type `noise.types.` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and it will list all types :

```
>>> noise.types.
                BLENDER
                CELLNOISE
                NEWPERLIN
                STDPERLIN
                VORONOI_CRACKLE
                VORONOI_F1
                VORONOI_F2
                VORONOI_F2F1
                VORONOI_F3
                VORONOI_F4
```

Comment: Meh, okay .. That's the only thing I didn't try. Thanks! Do you know why the api isn't mentioning them?

Comment: the API DOC needs some work

Comment: So the reason isn't that they could remove some of these the next version(s)? I only want to be sure that when I am using some of these it isn't going to be removed in the future.

Comment: I have no guarantee for that, but this noise is old and it's not included in old DOCs also